# Get downloaded bytes using MegaApiClient

Tags: c#, mega-api

I'm trying to get downloaded bytes (download buffer) using MegaApiClient, working with ProgressBar and I thought it was as simple as using WebClient... my code:

```
public async void MegaFileDownload(string URL)
        {
            var client = new MegaApiClient();
            if (Form3.User != "") await client.LoginAsync(Form3.User, Form3.Pass);
            else await client.LoginAnonymousAsync();

            var progress = new Progress<double>();

            Uri fileLink = new Uri(URL);
            CG.Web.MegaApiClient.INode node = await client.GetNodeFromLinkAsync(fileLink);

            progress.ProgressChanged += (s, progressValue) =>
            {
                progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(progressValue);
                label7.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
                if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
                {
                    progressBar1.Value = 0;
                    label3.Text = "0.00 MB";
                    label7.Text = "0%";
                    button2.Enabled = true;
                }
            };
```

Can you please help me? I didn't find documentation, I'm not that familiar with C#.
Thank you

**Edit:** I'm using Stream and Filestream to get my app working. Thanks.